# how to send string response in php

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to send the string response of a particular request from ftp Interface. I am using below code..

```
if($s == 'Successfull') {
    $rid = 's'.$request_id;            
}
if($s == 'Unsuccessfull') {
    $rid = 'e'.$request_id;            
}
echo "<b style='font-size: 16px;color:#59AB8F;'>Your Request ID:".$rid.".......<b>\n";
printf("<br>");
header($rid);
```

Comment: Successful*.  What is `header($rid)` supposed to be accomplishing?  Is this supposed to be an API-like response?

Comment: I dont see anything over here..give some more details.

Comment: I found it from net that we can sand request in string like this header('http response'). here request id is..$request_id = $date->getTimestamp();

Comment: here I created code for ftp interface in which when file has successfully downloaded, I sand a response in string with a request id. the requested url is like this- getFTPFiles.php?IP=IP1&USERID=USERID1&PASSWORD=PASS1&REMOTE_ADDRESS=Remote_address1&LOCAL_ADDRESS=local_address1&NO_OF_FILES=1&File_Name=File1.           so my query is how to sand response in string?

Comment: So this is a GET?  What is request_id signifying?  I  gave an example for handling a POST response.

Comment: I am to send post response..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not set a response code with a JSON response?

```
if($s == 'Successfull'){
  http_response_code(201); 
  $data = [ 'id' => $request_id ]; 
}
else {
  http_response_code(400);    
}

if (isset($data)) {
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

That would be the normal way of handling an API POST response.  201 signifies a resource was created, 400 signifies a bad request (you can change this if a different response code matches better).  Then the client can read in the JSON data and get the id.

Comment: but I don't want to sand response in json or xml format. I am to simply sand response in a string

Comment: You don't want machines to be able to read the request ID?

Comment: you are right json and xml formate are readable by machines but I am to know that how can we send response in a simple string.

Comment: Just echo the string then, I'm not sure what you're trying to do.